# Compiling error on codekit when using sass, compass, and susy

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

Whenever I try to save a .scss file that is linked in codekit, i get the following error:

"Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:

LoadError on line 161 of /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/bin/../lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: no such file to load -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace"

Does anyone know why? I can't proceed until I get this sorted out. I have tried to update & uninstall/install all of these gems and also codekit itself.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install Sass, Compass as well as Susy within the terminal. Now go to the Codekit preferences. Languages-> Compass  and within Advanced Compiler Settings choose the radio button "Use the Compass executable at this path" (/usr/bin/compass). Afterwards you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Install all gems (yes, susy should be first in place):

```
sudo gem install susy    
sudo gem install compass
sudo gem install sass (not sure if needed but installed it.)
sudo gem install toolkit
sudo gem install compass-normalize
sudo gem install compass-rgbapng
```

Answer (score -1):

Codekit comes with Sass and Compass, it shouldn't be required to install custom libraries.

The error message indicates that the problem is in the Codekit libraries, maybe contacting Codekit developer would be the best option here.

Comment: Negative. CodeKit developer here. As the CodeKit Help page explains, it's currently required to use an externally-installed version of Compass if you want to use Compass plugins. This is because those plugins expect to be running from system-standard locations; not from within CodeKit's app bundle. I'm working on a way to do this, but for now the only way to use plugins is to switch CodeKit to use an externally installed version of Compass.